# Can someone tell me what this part is?

Tags: part-identification

I wanted to make something from the "Forbidden LEGO" book and I came across a piece, I don't know what the part number is.

[image]

The piece has 5 peg holes, one axle hole, half a gear, last of all I don't know, but in the instructions, it looks like there are 2 half peg holes. What is the part?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Technic Gearbox Half](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32166&name=Technic,%20Gearbox%20Half&category=%5BTechnic,%20Gear%5D#T=C). It's very easy to find by searching "technic gear" on BL.

[image: gear]

The item number is 32166, and it was available in the early 2000s (specifically from 1999-2002).

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate it.